# Converting navbar in hidden hamburger menu

Tags: html, css

So I created a nav-bar and now, for mobile devices, I just want to display the logo and a hamburger menu which (when opened) displays the `<li>`'s and the social media icons (those are on the html but i'm not able to give them any width). I don't want the old nav bar menu on the back, I tried giving it a display: none on the media queries or a background-color: transparent but none are working.

Basically I want the burger menu to display the li's and the box with the social media icons, all of this displayed vertically.

How would be the best approach to get this result given the following code?

```css
.showcase .nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: var(--branding);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 90;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
}

.nav-logo {  /*CHECK WHEN UPLOADING LOGO*/
  width: 14rem;
  margin: auto .5rem;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links li {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links a {
  color: var(--lightgrey);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links li:hover,
.nav-links li:focus {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-social {
  margin: 0 2rem .5rem 2rem;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-social a {
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--lightgrey);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.hamburger {
  margin: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.hamburger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  margin: .4em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .showcase {
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .nav-bar {

  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 80vh;
    top: 8rem;
    background-color: var(--branding);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="../src/images/logo.svg" alt="LBH Logo" class="nav-logo"></a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#srv">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#soc">Social</a></li>
    <li><a href="#inf">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="nav-social">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram "></i>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you have `display:flex`, you also need to put `flex-direction: column` in order to have stuff displayed vertically.

That said you might not even need `display:flex` because the default `display` of the elements you're using is `block` which makes their content stack vertically anyway.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to keep the logo where it is and "get rid" od the rest of the stuff. Then display the burger menu which, on click, displays on vertical the <li>'s and the box with the social media icons. I applied a display: flex just to lay out and center everything nicely on my desktop view, now as the logo is inside the nav, I don't know how to extract it and get rid of the rest, leaving the logo where it is with no background but the burger on the right hand side. Hope it's clearer now